# Split Date and Time from system::DateTime

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-cli

Is there any way to split the date and time from the System::DateTime?

Now you get something like: 2012-03-01 16:12:555

Is there any to separate them?

Comment: Be sure to use the MSDN Library effectively, you won't get far without being able to look up the members of a class.  When you do, you'll have no trouble finding the Date property to get the date and the TimeOfDay property to get the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `DateTime` and you want to split it into date and time, you can use the properties `Date` and `TimeOfDay`:

```
DateTime now = DateTime::Now;
DateTime date = now.Date;
TimeSpan time = now.TimeOfDay;
```

But if you only want to get the string representation of the date and time, you don't need those properties. You can use `ToString()` along with [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime):

```
String^ dateString = now.ToString("d");
String^ timeString = now.ToString("T");
```

One things you should remember about formatting in .Net is that it depends on the current culture. That means the result of calling `ToString()` will be formatted differently on a computer with Czech culture than on a computer with American culture.

Comment: @svick When i add using namespace System or using System it's show me error on System , i am using visual c++ VS 2010

Comment: @Ahmad I don't see how is that relevant to this question, but you probably [don't have C++/CLI enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4969389/41071). Next time, when you have a question, [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), that's what this site is for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create DateTime object like

```
Datetime test = DateTime::Now;
```

Then format it like this

```
String^ timestamp = test.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");
```

This format is compatible with MySQL.

Comment: String^ timestamp = test->ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");

-> should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well for date you can use [Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) 
For the time you can use [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx)

Comment: I got 6 errors:
Can't show them ... Need to learn bb codes, will edit soon

Comment: String^ GrabTime()
{
 System::DateTime::Today CurDate = System::DateTime::Today; // Get Current Time.
 System::DateTime::TimeOfDay CurTime = System::DateTime::TimeOfDay;
 return CurDate.ToString();//Date
 return CurTime.ToString();//Time
}