# VS2015 with sdl2 error : "#using needs c++/cli mode enabled"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

I've been trying to follow lazy foo's productions tutorial on sdl2 and I keep on running into the same issue. I made a template that links to the correct files and all and it worked for a while. But now when I create a project and include iostream for example, it tells me #using need c++/cli mode enabled.

So I then tried enabling it in the project settings but then it gave another error : "Cannot open metadata file iostream"

I tried :
Rebuilding the project and solution

Cleaning the project and solution

I read this question and its answers : [Visual studio - getting error "Metadata file 'XYZ' could not be found" after edit continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490857/visual-studio-getting-error-metadata-file-xyz-could-not-be-found-after-edi)

Tried this too : [IntelliSense: "#using" requires C++/CLI to be enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969325/intellisense-using-requires-c-cli-to-be-enabled)

All of the above did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse `#include`, `using` and `#using`.

`#using` is used to import class libraries in C++/CLI, which is something you won't ever need unless you work with .NET libraries (but then usually you are better off just using C#, unless you are writing interop code).

`#include` is for including header files, which is what you normally do in "regular" C++. `<iostream>` is a regular standard library header, so you need `#include` (as in `#include <iostream>`).

`using` instead is used to bring names in the current scope (either the whole content of a namespace - as in the dreaded `using namespace std;`) or single names (as in `using std::cout;`). From C++11 it's also used to enable constructors inheritance and to create type aliases, but for the moment I don't think you need to worry about these uses.

But most importantly: please take the time to *first* learn the basics of the language from reputable sources before trying random stuff. All this `#using` mess wouldn't have arisen if you even just looked first at the classic hello would example you can find everywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Haha, ok thanks. It was just a dumb mistake because I was using unity before... with c#...